# AWS Cognito "in which userpool our user was found"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-cognito

I was going through the Amplify docs on tutorial about how to integrate Amplify auth in my app. I amplify cli we have option that we can use multiple cognito user pools in our app. My questions is "if we have multiple user pools, how can we know the user pools in which our user was found in".
This is the sample code for authentication on amplify docs.https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin/q/platform/android/#register-a-user.

```
Amplify.Auth.signIn("username", "password",
    { result ->
        if (result.isSignInComplete) {
            Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Sign in succeeded")
        } else {
            Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Sign in not complete")
        }
    },
    { Log.e("AuthQuickstart", "Failed to sign in", it) }
)
```

using this code how can I determine the user pool in which our user was found.
Suppose I have two user pools "students" and "teachers" if a user sign in using his username how can I know weather he belongs to student user pool or teacher user pool

Comment: Is there a reason you are using multiple user pools instead of groups? To answer your question though, you have to explicitely state the user pool id when authenticating a user so you would already know which pool a user belongs to since you passed it when authenticating them.

Comment: Can i achieve my desired results by user group..... If so how?

Comment: A group is a collection of users in a single user pool so you can use the same user pool id to sign in users.

If you really want to use your current approach, you can try signing the user in and you will get `UserNotFoundException` if the user doesn't belong to the user pool you used. You can catch that exception and try the other one.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i do it using Amplify Auth. I have understanding of how can i do it using pool id. But how can i do it using Amplify Auth? Can you show me some code?

Comment: Since you are just starting out, you should really use user groups. This is what they have been made for. You can have different roles for users of different groups. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-api-gateway-and-iam/